# How to put a small angularjs app on my codepen

Tags: angularjs, codepen

I try to upload a small angularjs app to my code pen. My question is: how to put the views?

I have two views. So they're in two separate .html files. But on code pen you have only one .html placeholder.

What I tried to do, is to put them in a  tag with id, but it's doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<!--  html templates used by angular, usually in separate files -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="albumDetails.html">
  <div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="albumDetails in albumDetails  | searchFor:searchString">

        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="p-2"><img src="img/photo_album.png" class="albumIcon img-fluid" /></div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <p><strong>Album title:</strong> <a href="#/photos/{{albumDetails.id}}">{{albumDetails.title}}</a></p>
                <p><strong>Owner’s name:</strong> {{albumUsers[albumDetails.id].name}}</p>          
                <p>Number of Photos: {{ 'PhotoDetails[$index]' | lengthOfObject }}  </p>    
            </div>

        </div>  
        <hr />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
  <!--  template for displaying a contacts info  -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="calbumList.html">
  <div>
<p><a href="#/albums">Go back to home page</a></p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="PhotoDetails in PhotoDetails">
        <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".photoBig{{PhotoDetails.id}}"><img src="{{PhotoDetails.thumbnailUrl}}" /></a>       

        <div class="modal fade photoBig{{PhotoDetails.id}}" id="modalContainer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel{{PhotoDetails.id}}" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <img src="{{PhotoDetails.url}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the pen: 
https://codepen.io/Menachem36/pen/eedbgb

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: use plunker instead

Comment: I was thinking about that. But since I'm using it on my resume, I don't want too many links. Try to have codepen & github. Any idea how to implement it on codepen?

Comment: Where is the ngRoute file?

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=albumModule&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.5%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.5%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%...

Comment: It's in the module declaration. See the codepen - at the top of the .js

Comment: Why don't create one directive or component with that HTML inside of each one? And call these elements from the HTML view.

Comment: Instead of routing? and then what about the routing?